# Yahoo weather API giving errors for certain US lat/lng locations

Tags: php, yahoo-api, yahoo-weather-api

I am creating pages about parks.  For each park, there is a lat/lng and for most parks, I am able to use the Yahoo weather API

But for some reason, some pages return errors like this:

Invalid Input /forecastrss?w=2347563

After a call that I make like this to the Yahoo weather API:

http://www.geomojo.org/cgi-bin/reversegeocoder.cgi?long=-121.433098&lat=40.509312

Any idea how I can resolve these sorts of errors?

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'http://www.geomojo.org/cgi-bin/reversegeocoder.cgi?long='.$lng.'&lat='.$lat;


// Calls the url to get the zip code and woeid
$webpage = file_get_contents($url);
//echo $webpage;
try
{
     $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, 0, true);

     // Gets the woeid to look up the weather in that specific place dynamically.
     $woeid= $xml->woeid; // Displays "Text"
     $zip =  $xml->name; // Displays "Text"

    // URL to send to yahoo weather to get weather RSS
        $yahoo_url = 'http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w='.$woeid;

    $xml = file_get_contents($yahoo_url);
    $yahoo_response = new SimpleXMLElement($xml , 0, false);

    $weather_description = $yahoo_response->channel->item->description;

    $splitdata = explode('<a', $weather_description);
    echo '<p>'.$splitdata[0].'</p>';
}
catch  (Exception $e)
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Here is a url of an example where this doesn't work.  See the weather section on the left side:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/parks/park.php?park_id=86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This geocoding call

http://www.geomojo.org/cgi-bin/reversegeocoder.cgi?long=-121.433098&lat=40.509312

is only returning a state, California.

If I had to make a wild guess, I'd say the weather API needs a more specific location than that.  This may be because some parks are so remote (or the nearest town so small) that the geocoder can't find a city for the coordinates you're passing.

Answer (score 2):

You might get better results if you do both the lat/long->woeid and weather calls through Yahoo. You can use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) to do both calls for you.

For example, using your lat/long pair above, here's a YQL query that first converts the lat/long pair into a woeid, then uses that to get the forecast:

[`select * from weather.woeid where w in (select woeid from geo.placefinder where text="-121.433098, 40.509312" and gflags="R")`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20weather.woeid%20where%20w%20in%20%28select%20woeid%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%22-121.433098%2C%2040.509312%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22%29&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

When tried in the YQL console, here are the results:

```
<query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
    yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2011-12-30T20:43:08Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <results>
        <rss version="2.0"
            xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0">
            <channel>
                <title>Yahoo! Weather - Old Station, CA</title>
                <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Old_Station__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA0801_f.html</link>
                <description>Yahoo! Weather for Old Station, CA</description>
                <language>en-us</language>
                <lastBuildDate>Fri, 30 Dec 2011 11:53 am PST</lastBuildDate>
                <ttl>60</ttl>
                <yweather:location city="Old Station"
                    country="United States" region="CA"/>
                <yweather:units distance="mi" pressure="in" speed="mph" temperature="F"/>
                <yweather:wind chill="51" direction="200" speed="7"/>
                <yweather:atmosphere humidity="89" pressure="30.08"
                    rising="2" visibility="4"/>
                <yweather:astronomy sunrise="7:33 am" sunset="4:52 pm"/>
                <image>
                    <title>Yahoo! Weather</title>
                    <width>142</width>
                    <height>18</height>
                    <link>http://weather.yahoo.com</link>
                    <url>http://l.yimg.com/a/i/brand/purplelogo//uh/us/news-wea.gif</url>
                </image>
                <item>
                    <title>Conditions for Old Station, CA at 11:53 am PST</title>
                    <geo:lat>40.59</geo:lat>
                    <geo:long>-121.49</geo:long>
                    <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Old_Station__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA0801_f.html</link>
                    <pubDate>Fri, 30 Dec 2011 11:53 am PST</pubDate>
                    <yweather:condition code="26"
                        date="Fri, 30 Dec 2011 11:53 am PST" temp="51" text="Cloudy"/>
                    <description><![CDATA[
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/26.gif"/><br />
<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
Cloudy, 51 F<BR />
<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />
Fri - Rain/Snow Showers. High: 43 Low: 21<br />
Sat - Partly Cloudy. High: 48 Low: 23<br />
<br />
<a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Old_Station__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA0801_f.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
(provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
]]></description>
                    <yweather:forecast code="5" date="30 Dec 2011"
                        day="Fri" high="43" low="21" text="Rain/Snow Showers"/>
                    <yweather:forecast code="30" date="31 Dec 2011"
                        day="Sat" high="48" low="23" text="Partly Cloudy"/>
                    <guid isPermaLink="false">USCA0801_2011_12_31_7_00_PST</guid>
                </item>
            </channel>
        </rss>
    </results>
</query>
```