# Yahoo Weather API not support for some WOIED

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, yql, yahoo-api

I am using yahoo weather api for my iphone application. What I am doing is, tracking user's current location and then get the WOEID. Then I request weather info for that WOEID (http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastjson?w=2189675)

But weather API support for only few WOEID of local cities, others give "null" ... How can I solve this problem. Is there a way to get the WOEID of the main cities which are supported weather API?

If anyone have faced this problem, Please give me a help to solve this issue.

Comment: you can always use the location of the device using lat long .... refer this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951839/api-to-get-weather-based-on-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Following Ankit's comment, you could go from lat/long to WOEID, then from WOEID, all in one YQL call. (This copied from my answer to a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514796/yahoo-weather-api-giving-errors-for-certain-us-lat-lng-locations/8683951#8683951).)

A sample call would look like the following (click to see it in the YQL console):

[`select * from weather.woeid where w in (select woeid from geo.placefinder where text="-121.433098, 40.509312" and gflags="R")`](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.woeid%20where%20w%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%22-121.433098%2C%2040.509312%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys)

Note this may not result in a suitable weather forecast 100% of the time, but I've found it to be more reliable than previous WOEID methods.